# The messages I send in the chat are displayed, but the files are not displayed

Tags: reactjs, laravel, file, chat, imagedownload

I'm developing a chat application with Laravel and ReactJS. I can send messages and files. However, when I send a file, only the file's path appears. How can I view a small preview of the file? Thank you in advance for your help.

I view my files and messages in this component.

```
class Message extends React.Component {
    static contextType = ChatContext;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            message: (this.props.message !== undefined ? this.props.message : ""),
            is_me: false
        };
    }

    render() {
        const { session } = this.context;
        const { message } = this.state;

        let date = "";
        let is_me = false;
        if (message.from.id === session.id) {
            is_me = true;
        }
        if (message.created_at) {
            date = moment(message.created_at).fromNow();
        }


        if(message.data !== null && JSON.parse(message.data) !== undefined){
            var data = JSON.parse(message.data);
            message.message = ("<img src='"+data.file_path+' style="max-size:100px;"/>' ?? data.file_path);
        }


        return (
            <div className={`chat ${is_me ? 'is-me' : 'is-you' }`}>
                {is_me ? null:(
                <div className="chat-avatar">
                    <div className="user-avatar bg-purple">
                        <span>{message.from.name.charAt(0)}{message.from.surname.charAt(0)}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                )}
                <div className="chat-content">
                    <div className="chat-bubbles">
                        <div className="chat-bubble">
                            <div className="chat-msg">{message.message}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <ul className="chat-meta">
                        <li>{message.from.name}</li>
                        <li>{date}</li>
                        {!is_me ? null: (
                        <li>{Lang.get('agent.seen')}</li>
                        )}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

My component is like this. The submitted files look like this "<img src='message-files/SGwmtyDNrK49387jtSWuPAGs2H4tvfdMGC503og4.png style="max-size:100px;"/>". I want to view this file.

Comment: I see you found my answer useful. Back to what I mentioned at the start. The 404 error code is because the browser cannot locate the resource at that url. I knew this was very likely so I mentioned it at the very beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a string as an element.

```
if(message.data !== null && JSON.parse(message.data) !== undefined){
    var data = JSON.parse(message.data);
    message.message = ("<img src='+data.file_path+' style='max-size:100px;' />" ?? data.file_path); /* <—- not allowed. message.message is simply a string. */
}
```

Instead you must create an `img` element which will be responsible for showing the images (*provided the `img` url is correct* <sup>[1]</sup>).

```
if(message.data !== null && JSON.parse(message.data) !== undefined)
{
    var data = JSON.parse(message.data);
    message.message = createElement('img', {src: data.file_path, style: {maxSize: '100px'}}); /* <—- now message.message is a usable element. */
}
```

*Aside:*

- Why the `?? data.file_path`? It is part of your code.
- What do you mean by *”How can I view a small preview of the file?”*

---

<sub>[1] I mentioned this because it is a very tricky part to get right.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

```
if (message.data !== null && message.data !== undefined) {
        try {
            var data = JSON.parse(message.data);
            if (data && data.file_path !== undefined) {
                message.message = React.createElement('img', {src: `${data.file_path}`, style: {maxWidth: '100px'}});
            } else {
                message.message = "Dosya bulunamadı";
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error parsing message data:", error);
        }
    }
```

I made this change in my code. The files I send appear as a small photo icon in the Chat panel. And I get a 404 error message in the browser console.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e22Ro.png)

Comment: How is this different from the already posted answer?

Comment: @Mikaila the user is new.